# Vanity URL not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using htaccess to try and rewrite a url.  I have tried about 10 versions of the code and examples but nothing makes any change.  I know mod_rewrite is working because it is adding www to the url, but the vanity URL won't work.

```
RewriteRule ^franchise/([0-9]+)/?$ franchise-information.php?franchiseid=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^franchise/([0-9]*?)/$ franchise-information.php?franchiseid=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

And here is the URL:

```
http://www.playballkids.com/franchise-information.php?franchiseid=162
```

Comment: Which URL are u trying to call?

Comment: Please post the complete `.htaccess` style file.

Comment: Do you start  you .htccess with `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /franchise-information\.php\?franchiseid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ franchise/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^franchise/(\d+)/?$ franchise-information.php?franchiseid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Problem I am having now is that the entire site is being rewritten to /franchise/  I only needs files that are franchise-information.php

Comment: That cannot happen with these rules. First rule'scondition is matching `/franchise-information\.php?franchiseid=...` and then redirecting.

Comment: Do you have other rules also?